# Sharepoint REST API - How to Create InformationRightsManagementSettings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

To create IRM settings using REST API, I am referring to document [SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings object](http://SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings%20object)

As per documentation, it suggest below REST endpoint to create new IRM
`POST http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/InformationRightsManagementSettings`

Howerver the post body is not given in documentation.

Need to understand how to set IRM setting object properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure information right management by CSOM in SharePoint online. Then you also configure IRM by REST API. Because the CSOM is the basic of the REST API. For more detailed information, check things below.

[Office 365 – Automating the Configuration of Information Rights Management (IRM) using CSOM.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/09/07/office-365-automating-the-configuration-of-information-rights-management-irm-using-csom/)

There is a similar post: [Sharepoint Online -O365- templates](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/d506e8a1-da38-415c-a7df-3b5797201ac4/sharepoint-online-o365-templates?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Check if the endpoint URI structure for InformationRightsManagementSettings object is correct according to the article below.

[SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings object.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247077(v=office.15))